# service-worker not working offline

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have successfully registered service-workers.js with no errors, and it has all the files required to work offline stored in [cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sYKo.png).
However, When i try to check if it'll respond `200` when offline,
[It fails!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkFiJ.png)

Here is the code:

```
//Delete Old Cache
caches.delete('[v0.1.0]');

//Latest CACHE_NAME
var CACHE_NAME = '[v0.1.1] Portfolio (ATB00ker)';

//Files to be Cached
var urlsToCache = [
    '../../../index.html',
    '../jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js',
    '../owl.carousel.min.js',
    '../scrollreveal.min.js',
    '../../images/bg-creator.webp',
    '../../images/icon/facebook.svg',
    '../../images/icon/telegram.svg',
    '../../images/icon/gmail.svg',
    '../../images/icon/github.webp'
];


self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  // Perform install steps
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function(cache) {
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
      })
  );
});


self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request, {ignoreSearch:true}).then(response => {
      return response || fetch(event.request);
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: Did you also follow the instructions to [Register a service worker on the site](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/offline/#register_a_service_worker_on_the_site) to add offline support back into the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem in my case was that i had put the service-worker.js in "assets/js/user", when i moved it to root directory "/" it worked!

Comment: I'm not sure why this works, but it does! I moved my sw.js to webroot, and voila I'm in business. Anyone have an explanation for this?

Answer (score 8):

You have `/index.html` cached offline but you are visiting `/` to test it. Those are two different paths and you will have to cache offline the one you want to visit.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you didn't cater for offline.  You have to direct the service worker to the offline page you want to display.  Here is a snippet of code:

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    console.log('Handling fetch event for', event.request.url);

    event.respondWith(            
        caches.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
            if (response) {
                console.log('Found response in cache:', response);

                return response;
            }

            console.log('No response found in cache. About to fetch from network...');

            return fetch(event.request).then(function (response) {
                console.log('Response from network is:', response);

                return response;
            }).catch(function (error) {                    
                console.error('Fetching failed:', error);

                return caches.match(OFFLINE_URL);
            });
        })
    );
});
```

Alternatively, you can have a look at [this](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/tree/gh-pages/service-worker/custom-offline-page).

Answer (score -3):

you must checklist "update on reload"
[image]